# Microsoft Exchange increase attachment size

Tags: microsoft, microsoft-graph

I followed the instructions to increase the attachment size as shown here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/04/15/office-365-now-supports-larger-email-messages-up-to-150-mb/

Its been a couple of days since I waited for the changes to go in but I still notice the issue: `The following files weren't attached because adding them would cause the message to exceed the maximum size limit of 34 MB`

What else I can do to increase the size of the attachment?

Based on the questions - I tried it on OWA with an existing mailbox.

Comment: 1. What did you increase it to? 2. Is this an existing mailbox or a new mailbox? If an existing mailbox did you increase it on the mailbox? 3. Are you sending from Outlook or from OWA? It sounds to me like you're sending from OWA, which has a 35MB file attachment size limit. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#message-limits-across-office-365-options

Comment: 1. Maximum limit, as shown in post. 2. Existing. Tried on both. 3. OWA (tried Outlook as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow up my post here (if it's an exchange on-premises)

https://messaging.faboit.com/2016/09/exchange-connectors-to-send-and-receive.html

You'd need to increase it in 2 sites, on the connector, and on the transport config.

Comment: Thanks @jose ortega - I was trying the OWA. Will give this a shot.